# OOP PHP - Sistema simples de CRUD e bloqueio criativo

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando Orientação a Objetos aplicado a PHP e estou me perdendo no básico; não me entra na cabeça como organizar os scripts e classes. Estudei Java OO e não tenho maiores problemas, mas iniciei meus estudos em PHP na forma procedural e agora não consigo entender como funciona, por exemplo, a classe contendo o 'main', no Java, responsável por fazer a coisa funcionar; como isso acontece no PHP.

Estou criando uma aplicação simples de CRUD, contendo:
- Uma página de boas vindas;
- Uma página de Login;
- E enquanto logado, terá acesso a uma página de cadastro, e uma de atualização de registros.

Já li vários códigos, artigos e tutoriais sobre OOP PHP, mas minha mente está bloqueada à entender isso.

Qual seria a forma enquadrada nas boas práticas de programação do PHP de criar esta aplicação? Um script de conexão separado ou integrado nas páginas? Utilizar abstração ou não? (Os usuários com acesso teriam permissões iguais, de cadastrar e atualizar cadastros). Todos os arquivos numa mesma pasta, ou tudo separado, ainda que seja um projeto apenas de aprendizado?
Li um pouco sobre MVC, é proveitoso estudar a fundo?

Como vocês fariam isso?

Comment: Só uma nota, no Java você não tem tais problemas por que ele "já vem" com tecnologias para tal, o PHP é mais livre para você criar as "coisas" do jeito que preferir. Recomendo que você comece usando um framework existente para PHP, sugestões: [Laravel](http://laravel.com), [cakePhp](http://cakephp.org), [codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com). I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com certeza é proveitoso estudar MVC, eu comecei a estudar e já estou desenvolvendo um sistema baseado nele. Até postei uma pergunta aqui no início porque de fato da um nó grande na cabeça para montar a lógica, mas depois que enxerga o sistema fica muito limpo e organizado.
Recomendo o seguinte tutorial, nele tem o que você precisa pra sua pergunta:

http://www.tutsup.com/2014/09/17/mvc-em-php-parte-1/

Talvez você deve até ter visto já por aí, mas acho que é um bom exemplo pra iniciar.

Uma dica grátis: Veja apenas a lógica do sistema, não precisa se prender a ele rigorosamente, terá coisas que será mais fácil fazer do seu jeito usando a lógica deles.